# Software to test userscripts in Chome

Tags: windows, linux, chrome

What software can be used to test userscripts in Chrome?

The obvious suggestion would be the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) extension, but [its EULA](https://tampermonkey.net/eula.php?ext=dhdg) only allows it to be used for personal, non-commercial use. Testing my own userscripts for compatibility with Chrome, when the sole purpose of such testing is to enable others to use my own userscripts, is not personal use, and the web site makes no mention of alternative paid licenses that allow other uses.

Which other software can I use instead? I know Chrome used to have built-in support for userscripts, but [this StackOverflow's question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome) and [this SuperUser question's answers](https://superuser.com/questions/767286/re-enable-extensions-not-coming-from-chrome-web-store-on-chrome-v35-with-enhan) indicates how crippled the functionality has become, and both suggest Tampermonkey instead. What options do I have?

It needs to work both on Windows and on Linux, either x64 or x86. FOSS preferred, but not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chromium builds for Windows](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) are available, and close enough. They can be installed through Chocolatey as well. Chromium does not have the restrictions on user scripts that Chrome has.

If I ever encounter a situation where a script does work in Chromium, but not in the matching version of Chrome, then the limited functionality to temporary enable user scripts in Chrome is enough to look into it.